# how to export bookmarks from sidekick and import it to chrome

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks, sidekick

I love Sidekick but I changed my PC so I need to sync sidekick bookmarks in current device to another sidekick or chrome in new device.

Anyone knows how to do that??

1. sidekick in current device => sidekick in new device
2. Or sidekick in current device => chrome in new device

Answer (score 0):

You can enter bookmark manager by entering this URL `sidekick://bookmarks/`. At the top right of the screen there is 3-dot option, which contains export-bookmarks feature.